# How to add google fonts in functions.php

Tags: wordpress, google-fonts

Hey guys I can't manage to get this working, this is my code

```
<?php 

//Adding the CSS and JS files

function HBUtheme_setup(){
    wp_enqueue_style('google-fonts', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,600;0,700;1,300;1,400&family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;1,300;1,400&display=swap', false);
    wp_enqueue_style('fontawesome', 'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('style', get_stylesheet_uri(), NULL, microtime(), all);
    wp_enqueue_script('main', get_theme_file_uri('/js/main.js'), array(), microtime(), true);
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'HBUtheme_setup');
```

For some reason I can't get this fonts to load.

Comment: are your other styles are working  and loading ?

Comment: `wp_enqueue_style('Roboto Slab', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab&display=swap', array(), microtime() );
    wp_enqueue_style('Raleway', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway&display=swap', array(), microtime());`
Never Mind I got it working. In case someone is curious I post it here.